# HTML 5 webpages display hapardzardly in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I recently started developing pages in HMTL 5 and everything works perfectly well in all other browsers except IE. What could be the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: You've not given anything like enough information here to give an accurate diagnosis. But if you're using HTML5 tags in IE8, then you need to use html5shiv or Modernizr, otherwise IE8 won't recognise the HTML5 tags properly.

Comment: @Spudley i added links to show the error in IE8 but I was told that it's not allowed so I took them down but thanx for the answer. Modernizr fixed the problem for me.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I know it's solved now, but for future ref, you just need to give more detail: eg specific tags were giving problems? Tell us about that. Did you do any analysis that might help us work it out? What have you tried already to fix it? (so we know you've actually tried and not just asked for help as soon as something broke, and also so we don't waste time with ideas you've already tried). And try cutting it down to a small sample of code that shows the problem; I don't want to wade through the code of your whole site but a small demo to pinpoint the issue can be helpful.

Comment: heh, sorry that was quite wordy, but hopefully it's helpful :)

Comment: I understand what you saying Spudley but how do you show a demo of a problem that has to do with aesthetic? All I could say was I was using html 5 and IE isn't displaying the website properly like firefox and other browsers are doing. Everyone else seem to get what the problem was so I don't see what you referring to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

If you are  building responsive website you should use

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

File you can download from http://www.initializr.com/

Answer (score 3):

IE does not understand the new HTML5 element, you need to include a script that enables those element for IE.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

More info: [html5 shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)

I always use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#html5inie), it does the same job for you:

Answer (score 2):

Thats because Internet Explorer interprets CSS And the new HTML5 tags differently than other browsers.

See: [css-differences-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/14/css-differences-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8/) on smashingmagazine.com

There is a HTML5 boilerplate available which eliminates some of the crossbrowser differences, but not all: [html5boilerplate.com](http://html5boilerplate.com/).

Also, in conjunction with the library [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) you are able to minimize the difference. But while you develop a website, you always do have to check the rendering in all the browsers on which they will appear, because different browsers don't render the same.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the CSS, IE does not recognize the html5 elements, and will display it as inline element. therefore a page will look broken.

Comment: I just edited my answer, tanks. Doesnt make my answer less usefull though, but thanks for the downvote. @Mark

Comment: Anser has much more useful content this way, thank you @Mark! You really know best!